# Lookbehind (Regex) in TeXworks

Tags: texworks

I'm using TeXworks (Version 0.4.5) and came in touch with its regular expression (regex) feature, recently. I made some adjustments of the syntax-highlighting, for instance, to practice.

Now I'm asking: **Is it possible that TeXworks doesn't support the lookbehind `(?<= )` expression?** At least in the Find&Replace dialogue? Because my regex-input gets marked "invalid" as soon as I try to use it there. Also, the TeXworks-manual doesn't list the lookbehind-, but it does list the lookahead-expression.

*The actual problem I want to solve:*
I want to replace `\verb+BLABLA+` by `\emph{BLABLA}`.
I tried to search for `\+(?<=verb\+.*)` and replace the match (which should be the closing `+`) by `}`. Then I'd search for `verb\+` and replace that by `emph{`.

I stumbled over the fact, that most regex-flavors don't support the `.*` or '.+' in a loobehind, though, which still leaves the question above unanswered.

**Secondly, how would you solve the actual problem if not via lookbehind?**

Comment: I've never heard of this feature though it definitely sounds interesting. In Kile, I would use something like `\\verb\+([^\+]*)\+` for find and `\\emph\{\1\}` for replace. Obviously that might not be quite right for TeX Works. For `sed` I would use something like `s/\\verb\+\([^\+]*\)\+/\\emph{\1}/g'`.

Comment: Regular expressions can only do certainly things: more powerful highlighting requires other approaches. That's I think a 'known limitation' of TeXworks: since it uses regex highlighting it can't match some other editors in terms of picking up non-regular input syntaxes ((La)TeX isn't regular).

Comment: @cfr TeXworks uses regex for syntax-highlighting (and for auto-completion?) and one can activate it to be used in find&replace as well. Your "`\1`-method" uses back references, right?

Comment: @cfr This one works!! Square brackets indicate a set that has to be (in this case *not* because of the `^`) matched, right?

@JosephWright I appearently don't know what regular expressions (and non-regular ones) exactly are...

Comment: @LCsa Yes and yes. The back reference refers to the stuff in `(...)` or `\(...\)`. The `[^\+]*` means any string of any length consisting of any character other than `+`.

Comment: @cfr Looks like your comment here was an answer: could you make it one?

Comment: @JosephWright OK. I thought this would be off-topic.

Comment: @cfr Well possibly borderline but as TeXworks does have regex searching and is TeX-focussed it's not unreasonable to ask it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of this feature though it definitely sounds interesting. I would just use regular expressions.

Implementations of regular expressions vary. Since I'm not familiar with TeXworks, I cannot say exactly which syntax to use but I'll give two examples.

In Kile, I would use something like this for find:

```
\\verb\+([^\+]*)\+
```

and for replace:

```
\\emph\{\1\}
```

For `sed` I would use something like

```
s/\\verb\+\([^\+]*\)\+/\\emph{\1}/g
```

So I'd write something like

```
sed 's/\\verb\+\([^\+]*\)\+/\\emph{\1}/g' <filename.tex> > <filename-new.tex>
```

or else I would use

```
sed 's/\\verb\+\([^\+]*\)\+/\\emph{\1}/g' <filename.tex>
```

check the output and then use

```
sed -i 's/\\verb\+\([^\+]*\)\+/\\emph{\1}/g' <filename.tex>
```

to do the substitution in place. (Don't use `-i` without checking the output first, though. Unlike your editor, the command line has no 'undo' unless you use version control!)

The `()` in Kile and `\(\)` in `sed` are *grouping* and *saving* part of the pattern. This is then reused in the replacement as `\1` which *refers back* to the corresponding part of the string being replaced.

`\` escapes what would otherwise be interpreted as a special character rather than part of the pattern. So `\\verb`, `\\emph` and `\+` are required for `\verb`, `\emph` and `+`.

`[]` matches any one of the characters specified. For example `[abc]` would match any of `a`, `b` or `c`. The `^` inside negates this. So `[^\+]` matches any character other than `+`.

`*` means zero or more of something. So `a*b` would match `b`, `ab`, `aab` and so on. Hence, `[^\+]*` matches any string of zero or more characters which does not include `+`.